# Pivoting the table and show column as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table, I want to pivot the table, my desired output is @tab2.

My table is as follows:

```
declare @tab1 table(name varchar(50),mobile varchar(10),address varchar(100))
insert into @tab1 values('Test','2612354598','CG-10')
select * from @tab1
```

My desired output is:

```
declare @tab2 table(colname varchar(50),value varchar(100))
insert into @tab2 values('name','Test'),('mobile','2612354598'),('address','CG-10')
select * from @tab2
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using SQL server you can use [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
SELECT colname, valueid
 FROM   
(SELECT CAST(name as varchar(100)) name, CAST(mobile as varchar(100)) 
 mobile, address FROM @tab1) p  
UNPIVOT  
 (valueid FOR colname IN   
  (name,mobile, address)  
 )AS unpvt;
```

You need to `CAST()` the columns so the type is the same for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

what are you looking is `Unpivot` not `Pivot`. Use `Unpivot` as follows. make sure that all columns have same datatype.

```
 select
  colname,
  value
from @tab1
unpivot
(
  value
  for colname in ([name]
      ,[mobile]
      ,[address]
     )
) unpiv;
```